# php script running time calculate in object oriented php

Tags: php, performance, oop, time

I am working on the interface and have large datasets and interested to calculate execution time of my running script and improve it later based on time. But dont know how to calculate time in my code and where to use it properly.
Here is my block of code from which resulting output is displayed.

```
<?php
class CSVFileWriter 
{
    public $filename;
    protected $filehandle;
    protected $counter = 0;
    protected $logger = NULL;

    public function __construct (\autodo\common\Logger $logger) {
        if (is_null($logger)) {
            $this->logger = new \autodo\common\NullLogger();
        }
        else {
            $this->logger = &$logger;
        }   
    }

    public function init() {
        // open/create file
        // maybe create tmp-File
    }

    public function process($data) {

        $tmp = $data->getCSV();
        /*
        @todo open file, write data
        */
        $this->logger->log("Write: ".$tmp, 
            \autodo\common\Logger::HINWEIS,
            7);

        $this->counter++;
    }

    public function finish() {
        // close file   

        $this->logger->log($this->counter." sets written to CSV", 
            \autodo\common\Logger::HINWEIS,
            5);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: as mentioned in my question dont know how to calculate time of this running script ..

Comment: That's not a running script, that's just a class definintion. Running script should instantiate this class and call its methods. And there is the place where you have to calculate execution time which is a trivial task.

Comment: What method do you want to measure execution time? process()?

Comment: no not separate method just want to see execution time ...this time only help me to improve my code ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hindmost is correct, this is a class definition and not a running script. As TrtG mentioned you need to choose wich method(s) you want to know the execution time of.  A class definition don't have a execution time. You can't calculate an execution time without executing something. If you want to know the execution time of your process you can try this:

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$timeStart = microtime_float();

//Execute something 
$writer = new CSVFileWriter (null);
$writer->init();
$writer->process($yourData);
$writer->finish();

$yourWriterProcessExecutionTime = microtime_float() - $timeStart;
```